# Prove that every function $g$ such that $f=g, \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$, if $f=\frac{xy^4}{x^3+y^6}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, continuity

What is the solution for this question? I don't see how I can prove this directly, I think a proof by contradiction is required but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Do you have a source for this theorem?

Comment: @DavidRaveh no, it is a problem a friend sent to me

Comment: You basically want to show that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy^4}{x^3+y^6}$ doesn't exist. That is equivalent to $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} g(x,y)$ not existing (for *any* $g=f$), which shows that $g$ isn't continuous. There are many, many examples of similar questions, see some results of [this search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bx%2Cy%5C%20%5Cto0%2C0%7D%5Cfrac%7Bxy%5E4%7D%7Bx%5E3%2By%5E6%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $2$ paths leading to $(0,0)$. Path $1$: $(x,y) = (t^2,t)$. For this path, $g(t^2,t) = \dfrac{t^2\cdot t^4}{(t^2)^3+t^6}=\dfrac{1}{2}$. And path $2$: $(x,y) = (2t^2,t)$. Again for this path: $g(2t^2,t) = \dfrac{2t^2\cdot t^4}{(2t^2)^3+t^6}=\dfrac{2}{9}$. Thus you get $2$ different limits for $2$ different paths leading to $(0,0)$. Hence there is no limit at $(0,0)$, and $g$ is discontinuous there.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ along different curves. If we approach along the line $y=x$, then we get $$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y^5}{y^3+y^6}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y^2}{1+y^3}=0$$

On the other hand, if we approach along the curve $x=y^2$ then we get $$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y^6}{2y^6}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Therefore, no matter what value you assign to $f(0,0)$, the resulting function cannot be continuous at $(0,0)$.